# Is there any way to integrate the Adaptive cards designer with Angular @latest version

Tags: javascript, angular, monaco-editor, adaptive-cards, adaptive-design

I want to integrate an Adaptive Cards Designer into the Angular application. I have created an application on stackblitz. But I am getting a problem with loading CSS and Monaco editor.

please anyone help me out to render or integrating the Adaptive card designer in Angular?

Please find the link below,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mfde8r?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Problems:

1. Not able to load CSS.
2. Not able to load Card Payload Editor and Sample Data Editor (Monaco Editor)

Comment: I brought it to a certain level, maybe some person might be able to take this forward [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tsjpfo)

Comment: @NarenMurali Thanks, man. now CSS is loaded properly now but still card payload still showing "Loading editor..."

Comment: @MohitFBrose sorry, that one needs a lot of R&D, if I find will let you know!

Comment: can anyone help me out to load the Monaco editor?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mfde8r?file=src/app/app.component.ts